# C# WCF with Log4Net fails just some logging

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net, .net-4.8

We have WCF Application built with .NET Framework 4.8, which uses Log4Net (level value="DEBUG") for logging. It is able to log everything on local machine in both debug and release mode.

But when the release verion is run on 2nd computer, it fails to log just some random loggings (which are of 'INFO' level).

The 2nd Computer: Windows 10 with .NET Framework 4.8 installed and admin rights available.

What could be the possible cause here?

Comment: Try to enable internal logging on the 2nd computer as seen here: https://blog.elmah.io/log4net-tutorial-the-complete-guide-for-beginners-and-pros/#troubleshooting-problems. This may reveal any errors happening inside of log4net. It could be many things. Like access constraints on directories or similar.

Comment: Try using [WCF Tracing and Message Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging). It helps you log and locate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone for your Suggestions. The issue was not with Log4Net, instead it was because of the 'lock' statement. A 'lock' was applied on the NetworkStream's I/O operations, and a same lock was used for different stream objects. Applying different locks for each stream object had solved the issue :)